# What about WebSafe colors

Tags: html, colors, background-color

My father with whom I'm going to create a website (I just got him away from using Dreamweaver and font-tags) keeps talking about WebSafe colors he has to use for the background images. I keep telling him that that was about 1999 but he doesn't believe me.

- What are WebSafe colors?
- When and where were they needed?
- What the hell anyway?

This is no joke.

Comment: Whatever you do don't mention Wc3 validation.

Comment: @Will Thats curious, whats wrong with w3c?

Comment: @Jonathan I think you misunderstood me.  If his dad is going ape---- over **web safe colors** you don't want him to learn how to validate his html.

Answer (score 4):

Look what I found in half a second

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

No longer relevant unless you have a 16-bit display pipeline.

Comment: If you have a 16-bit display, then you wouldn't need web-safe colors as you could have up to 65k colors (2^16).  The web-safe colors were really about **8-bit** displays, since 2^8 is 256 and the palette is 216 colors.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about websafe colors, most of them are way too ugly anyways. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think Websafe colors used to refer to the colers which can always be displayed, even if the computer is using a 256 color palette.

This does absolute not matter anymore, because any computer sold within the last 10 years have been using true color.